# invariant subspace of the inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question**:
Prove that if $T:V \to V$ is a linear map, which is invertible, then each invariant subspace of T is also invariant under $T^{-1}$. V is finite.

**Thoughts**
I thought about composing them and somehow getting the identity map (which is also included in the invariant subspace if multiplied by some vector w), But this doesn't seem too formal..

Comment: That is not (necessarily) true for infinite-dimensional spaces. Is $V$ assumed to be finite-dimensional?

Comment: As stated, the claim is not true. Let $V$ be the space of ufunctions $f\colon\mathbb Z\to\mathbb R$ and $Tf(k)=f(k+1)$. Then $\{f:f|_{\mathbb N}=0\}$ is invarinat under $T$ but not under $T^{-1}$.

Comment: forgot to mention V was finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V$ be an invariant subspace under $T$. This means $T(V) \subseteq V$.

Now, if $V$ is finite dimensional, and since $T$ is invertible, you can easily show that $dim(T(V))=dim(V)$ and hence we actually have $T(V)=V$

Now, let $v \in V$. Then $v=T(w)$ for some $w \in V$. Hence, $T^{-1}(V) \subseteq V.$

Answer (score 2):

If $W\subseteq V$ is $T$-invariant, then $T$ restricts to a linear map $T\vert_W:W\rightarrow W$. This map is injective since $T$ is injective. So, $T$ maps $W$ isomorphically onto $W$. Hence, $T^{-1}$ maps $W$ isomorphically onto $W$.